# How to dynamically append a record into an Array in flex?

Tags: javascript, arrays, apache-flex

I have an mxml view in flex, and I need to dynamically add data to a DataGrid component.

This is where the DataGrid is initialized:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" width="100%"
    dataProvider="{initDG}" >
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Identifier" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Name" />
    </mx:columns> 
</mx:DataGrid>
```

This is the script part:

```
private var DGArray:Array = new Array;

[Bindable]
public var initDG:ArrayCollection;

private function onCreation():void{
    initData();
}

public function initData():void {
   initDG=new ArrayCollection(DGArray);
 }

private function onShow():void{
    for (var child:Object in children) {
          var details:Array = null;
          if (child instanceof String) {
              var test:String = children[child].toString();
              details = test.split(",");
          }
          //Here I need to make an object like this one:
          // record = {Identifier: details[0] , Name: details[1]};

          this.DGArray.push(the record created);
    }


}
```

I did this method because it's working if `DGArray` was a static Array:

```
 private var DGArray:Array = [
     {Identifier:'001', Name:'Slanted and Enchanted'},
     {Identifier:'002', NAme:'Brighten the Corners'}];
```

Can anyone tell me how to create the record and add it to DGArray?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

### In short

Add or remove items through the `ArrayCollection` instance instead of through the `Array` instance.

### And here's why

`ArrayCollection` - as its name suggests - is in fact nothing but a wrapper around `Array`, adding some functionality to it that comes in handy when working with the Flex framework.

So when you do

```
initDG.addItem(theNewItem);
```

that new item will automatically also be added to the underlying Array.
Additionally this function will also dispatch a [CollectionEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/CollectionEvent.html), which will notify the `DataGrid` that the data in its dataProvider has changed and it should be redrawn to reflect those changes.

If on the other hand you do

```
DGArray.push(theNewItem);
```

like you did, you directly alter the underlying Array. This doesn't really break anything; you'll still be able to acces the new item through e.g. ArrayCollection.getItemAt() as well, but the DataGrid was never notified of the change, hence it didn't redraw and keeps displaying the old data.